# unknownhostexception in udp client/server

Tags: java, sockets

I am writing a simple udp client/server application but i am getting the

```
UnknownHostException
in 
ip = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
```

I am on windows and I can't figure out what to do. Please can anyone help? None of the other questions I saw helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enclosing the statement with try/catch block solved my problem